# symfony2 and phpunit does not work on lampp (ubuntu 15.x)

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

My symfony2 application is working with phpunit perfectly on wamp (windows) but when a change the environment and start to work on lampp (linux) after installing, I get the following error when run the test by typing phpunit -c app/:   `/opt/lampp/htdocs/VTALLY/src/Iballot/CmsBundle/Tests/Controller/ParliamentaryControllerTest.php:11

Caused by
Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException: The reserved indicator "@" cannot start a plain scalar; you need to quote the scalar at line 4 (near "arguments: [@security.context, @fos_user.user_manager]").`

Comment: what's the contents of your YAML file which contain arguments @security.context ? Are you versionning your code or copy/paste file ?

Comment: The code I just copy and past it within the linux environment

Comment: Use quotes around the `@what.ever`s.

Comment: I cannot change the file because it 's in the vendor !

Comment: What version of Symfony did you install?

Comment: I'm using symfony 2.7.8

Comment: Not possible. Symfony 2.7.8 wouldn't throw this exception.

Comment: Then how can I lie while I need help.

Comment: Check what's the Symfony version you've got there again: `composer show symfony/symfony` (look at the "versions" section). The solution is in my answer anyway. Either downgrade Symfony, or send a PR to the problematic bundle to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put any strings starting with `@` in quotes:

```
arguments:
    ["@security.context", "@fos_user.user_manager"]
```

Reserved characters, like `@`, should be quoted. Unquoted `@`s [were deprecated in Symfony 2.8](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16433). Symfony 3.0 will forbid you to use such definitions and will throw an exception.

If you don't have control over the bundle that registered the problematic configuration, send a pull request with a fix to the vendor. As a quick fix you can downgrade Symfony. 2.7 will work, as well as 2.8 (the later will only emit a deprecation notice).

Comment: should I make a change within the vendor ?? I cannot !

Comment: Send a PR to the vendor to fix this.

Comment: Or use an older version of Symfony.