# The reserved indicator "@" cannot start a plain scalar

Tags: symfony, phpunit, yaml

Using PHPUnit 5.2.3 with Symfony 2.6.11 and php 5.6.18, I'm getting the error

> The reserved indicator "@" cannot start a plain scalar

My yaml files are well escaped with quotes.
This happens for many of the dependencies of my project.

Following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34990520/305189) I would have to update and/or submit a PR.

Would I have to do that all my dependencies ? Isn't there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: Could you also show where this `@` is located and failing?

Comment: Try to use single quotes in parameters, config files, etc..

Comment: Quoting of "@" was deprecated in Symfony 2.8, and removed in Symfony 3.0. You used an unaffected version (2.6, you should upgrade to a supported version by the way), so it's weird you get this error. There's no way around it anyway, so you'll need to get this fixed before upgrading.

Comment: That's also why I specified the versions I'm using. This issue is happening only when I use phpunit on my project. I only need to run some tests and I wonder how I can fix this without modifying the yml of all the vendors concerned...

Comment: I don't think you used 2.6 version of the yaml component. The deprecation message is not there at this version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same error with Symfony 2.3.

Instead of using `php phpunit.phar` from your project directory, use the one from the vendor `./vendor/bin/phpunit`.

Alternatively, you can use a `phpunit-old.phar` that is [version 4.8](https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-old.phar). This version is less strict about quotes in config files.

Source: iget-master comment [on this page](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2014).